# "Not allowed to load local resource" error executing PHP-script from the server

Tags: php, database, postgresql, server

I uploaded on a server (to a "public_html" directory) a simple PHP-script from
[the website of PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php). Here it is:

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=... dbname=... user=... password=...")
or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

// Performing SQL query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM authors';
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
}
echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

The server is a kind of a hosting (I do not have root privileges). The response of my browser is "Not allowed to load local resource" (Chromium) and "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" (MS Edge). All the other PHP-files in "public_html" directory work properly. I have an access to the DB itself - I can read and modify it using my login and password.

I think the problem is in the interaction between this PHP-file and the database. How can I solve it?

Comment: A 500 error is usually critical error. Syntax or some other stopping the program from compiling. You need to be able to access the web server error log to see what is happening.

Comment: @JasonK, Yes, you're right: I checked logs and there is a "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect()" error in them. But isn't it defined by default?

Comment: Oddly most of the big parts of php are libraries that need to be install separately.

Comment: Can I do it somehow without changing a php.ini?

Comment: No. Root is going to have to do that.

Comment: All right, thank you for your answer!